# Adding a class in check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I search through the net and cannot find a way. So far, I have tried:

```
<%= check_box_tag "course[location_ids][]", location.id, class: 'checkbox-inline'%>
```

This will output:

```
input type: "checkbox" name="course[location_ids][] id="course_location_ids_" value="1" checked="checked"
```

For some reason, it makes a checked input.

```
<%= check_box_tag "course[location_ids][]", location.id, :class => 'checkbox-inline'%>
```

does the same as the first one

How do I add a class inside of a check_box_tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not using the proper format

> ```
> check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
> ```

Change the tag to the following:

```
<%= check_box_tag "course[location_ids][]", location.id, false, class: 'checkbox-inline'%>
```

**Note:** The 3rd option is checked value, you need to change it according to your need

Refer: [**`check_box_tag`**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)